# Polymorphic Association - How to create a main index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I am creating an application that allows users to make comments on project postings created.  I followed this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association?) to set up polymorphic associations.

Based on the tutorial, the index page in the controller is set up as detailed below takes you to localhost:3000/projects/1/comments.

**Question: How do I route it and adjust the def index in the controller so that I can instead route index to localhost:3000/comments because I want to create a view that lists all comments regardless of which project it was posted on?  Because right now, based on the routes and code below, when I go to localhost:3000/comments, I get the following error:**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#index
Couldn't find Comment without an ID
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:32:in `load_commentable'
```

/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :load_commentable
    def index
        @comments = @commentable.comments
    end

private
    def load_commentable
        resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
        @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :projects do
    resources :comments
end

resources :comments
```

Comment: And your comment model includes this line:  `belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true`, along with your other associations? (You may want to include these in your answer.)

Comment: Yes, it does include that line. Does it affect how we can create a general index page?

Comment: My thought was that if the association wasn't set up properly to begin with, you wouldn't be able to call commentable.comments.

Comment: The whole thing works fine based on the tutorial, but the comment pages are for each specific project at localhost:3000/projects/#/comment. I am looking for consolidation all at localhost:3000/comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I created a new controller page:

route.rb

```
match 'comments' => 'comments#admin'
```

comments_controller.rb

```
def admin
    @newcomments = Newcomment.newest.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up your routes.rb file something like:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :comments
end

resources :comments
```

Comment: Yup, I had that set up already and did not work. I added more detail in my question above.

Comment: Your routes says photos instead of projects, is this correct?

Comment: My mistake, I copy and pasted the wrong one, but yes, my routes currently say projects. My guess is something I need to adjust in my controller but I'm not sure how to go about it?

Comment: Have you restarted the rails server since changing the routes?

Comment: Yup I did. going to localhost:3000/comments creates ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error as noted in question above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are routing the `index` action to localhost:3000/comments, it sounds like you are using a named route (i.e. 'comments' instead of 'index'). If you are using a named route, did you specify in the `routes.rb` file which controller action to hit? For instance, you should have:

```
match 'comments' => 'comments#index'
```

and your view file should be titled `index.html.erb`.

Also, if you are nesting your comments resource, you still need to declare

```
resources :comments, only: :index                     # not nested
```

For your route to work.

Comment: I did not have that instance. I tried adding that instance and created a file in my view/comments/comments.html.erb but my localhost:3000/comments now says ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find Comment without an ID

Comment: Sorry, I just revisited some apps I made similar to yours and my file name was incorrect (index.html.erb). I revised the post in light of this.

Comment: Oh, I already do have an index.html.erb file. As mentioned above, the index page is currently reached by localhost:3000/projects/#/comments, and not by localhost:3000/comments, which is what I am looking to do.